# Log on microSD card with STM32F4 based boards and Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, stm32f4

I would like to log signals on microSD card using STM32F429ZI and SPI/SDIO pzsmocn card adapter connected to the board using SDIO interface.
In STM32CubeMX I configured .ioc file with FATFS mode on "SD Card" and SDIO mode on "SD 4 bits Wide bus".

After the abovementioned setup I tried to log signals on Simulink using the approach reported [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/stmicroelectronicsstm32f4discovery/ug/sd-card-logging.html).
The result is that Simulink model building procedure ends successfully but any file is saved on microSD card and all the other model functionalities stop to work suddenly (Leds, CAN comunication).

I checked the procedure many times but I am not able to find what is not correctly going on.
I suppose that there is something missing or wrong in my setup, any advice is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.